# Extrude flat surface to curved surface for 3D printing

Tags: mesh, 3d-printing

I'm still new to Blender so I don't know all of the terminology and can't seem to phrase my question properly. But I am learning every day to model for 3D printing. Mainly custom PVC fittings to build things.

My current project requires that I take a flat surface (the top of a cylinder) and move it (maybe extrude is a better term) to the curved surface of another cylinder to merge the 2 meshes. I don't want to go past the surface since the object is hollow. What I have done in the past is overlap objects and then complete union and difference Boolean operations to cut and merge objects. But when I use the 3D tools in this project to diagnose issues I can't seem to resolve the issues. I visually cannot "see" the issues to resolve them.

So I want to see if it is possible to manually move  the vertices / flat surface to the curved surface "manually" so that I can see if this will be a better workflow or produce the desired results without errors (or minimal errors).
[image: screenshot of surfaces]

**Update:** Here's what I did and the errors that I received in the 3D-Print panel.

I expanded the bottom cylinder into the upper "U" cylinder but I want the space in-between removed.
[image]

So I copied the upper "U" cylinder and then completed a Bool Tool Difference to get this.
[image]

Then I removed the upper section of the differenced mesh since I do not want that any longer. (I just selected and deleted the vertices - there may be a better way but not too sure how to do so just yet.)

[image]

I then brough back in the upper "u" cylinder.
[image]

Then completed a Bool Tool Union then run the 3d-Print Check all and the is what I get.
[image]

Comment: Which 3D tools give you errors? And what kind of errors?

Comment: @taiyo, I updated my post with the errors that I am encountering.

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: For some 3d printing processes you do not need a single connected mesh(no need for boolean operation at all). I use Cura with an FDM printer and it works fine with multiple meshes in a single object just overlapping as long as their normals point in the right directions. No point in doing work that is not needed for the purpose. In other situations, when you need bevels for example, the parts must be connected, but not for 3d printing.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys don't need a single connected mesh?! That's interesting. I use Cura to slice with a stock Ender 3 V2. I'll have to try this to see what happens. I appreciate the feedback and suggestion!

Comment: Yep. Even [separate objects that overlap are sliced OK](https://imgur.com/Qf2zM2C), if their separate geometries are good(manifold, no holes, no wrong normals and so on)

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys, I have tried what you have suggested and this is the simplest and, in my opinion, the correct solution. It also allows for flexibility when creating 3D objects so that you can modify the details easily. I now need to look into stacking Boolean modifiers (which appears to be editable) as opposed to using the Bool Tool (which appears to be permanent changes). If you provide an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @JoeFletch Sorry for the delay. I wrote the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Boolean operations might not be needed at all for 3D printing

Some 3d printing processes do not require joint meshes so boolean operations might not be necessary at all. For example if you are planning to print with an FDM printer, most slicers (like Cura for example) will deal with separate overlapping geometry just fine if the separate geometry is tidy and suitable for 3d printing (no holes, no non-manifold geometry, no inconsistent normals or problematic concave n-gons). This might also make editing easier, if modifications are needed in the future since you don't need to deal with complicated geometry at all. You can keep the disconnected mesh parts in one objects or you can even have multiple overlapping objects for this to work.

As you can see you can have 3 separate objects in Blender:

[image]

And once you export them in STL format and then import to Cura(or possibly other slicers), it will slice just fine:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can probably fix your current object, but you could use the *Knife Project* tool instead:

Create a new object > circle (here 16 vertices), put it above the cylinder, deselect, select the cylinder, switch to *Edit* mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> to select the circle object, then *Mesh > Knife Project*:

[image]

Now you have the circle drawn on the surface of the cylinder, you can delete your circle object:

[image]

Remove the single vertices to get something like that:

[image]

Extrude up, flatten on Z:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows try importing the final mesh onto windows 3D builder. Its auto fix tool is pretty good at making the mesh manifold for 3d printing.

If you want a manifold mesh then projecting the top face of the bottom cylinder on the other wouldn't give you that, I think.

Instead, take both cylinders and join them into 1 object.
[image]
In edit mode, selecting only one cylinder, Face->Knife Intersect
[image]
This will create geometry where the faces intersect.
[image]
You can then go to Select->By trait->Interior faces, and delete them. Merge the rest by distance and recalculate normals just in case.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the top cylinder without resizing it to cut the bottom? If you do that then the faces are going to overlap when you join them and there's a higher chance of having issues. Instead cut the top of the bottom object with a solid cylinder that has a smaller radius than the top one, but bigger than the inner hole

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but you can "manually" move the vertices to the other surface to have a look.

Select the top face of your cylinder and separate it from the mesh. Add a *Shrinkwrap* modifier to it and select the other cylinder as target. Set the *Wrap Method* to *Project*. This will move all vertices up to the other surface. Probably all the options of the *Shrinkwrap* modifier are also useful for you.

[image]

After applying the modifier, you can adjust the vertices to keep the mentioned errors minimal and for example *Bridge Edge Loop* the projected ring and the top edge loop of your cylinder again.

[image]

Comment: This is a really great way to do this but I still get a significant amount of errors / issues in the 3D print toolbox. Keeping in mind that I have a low level of experience with this, it appears that when I union the 2 meshes, Blender is keeping the internal surfaces between the 2 meshes and identifying them as Non Manifold Edges. I may have to go back and do a difference of the surface of the upper cylinder to "cut" a hole in it and then union the 2 meshes to see what happens. It's late for me, so I will have to try this tomorrow. I much appreciate the potential solution and direction here.